# Opencart 2x: Unable to add more than 16 options to the product

Tags: php, product, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.3.0.2 version. I have created a product option i.e Product Color from `Catalog > Option`. When I am trying to assign this option to a product, I can only add 16 options. When I am trying to add the 17th option then I am getting a list of errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: type in path_to_the_site_folder/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 192
Notice: Undefined index: option_id in path_to_the_site_folder/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 211
Notice: Undefined index: value in path_to_the_site_folder/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 211
Notice: Undefined index: required in path_to_the_site_folder/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 211
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at path_to_the_site_folder/admin/controller/startup/error.php:34) in path_to_the_site_folder/system/storage/modification/system/library/response.php on line 12
```

Here is php.ini file of admin folder:

```
    magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
    register_globals = Off;
    default_charset = UTF-8;
    memory_limit = 64M;
    max_execution_time = 36000;
    upload_max_filesize = 999M;
    max_input_vars = 9000;
    max_post_size = 999M;
    safe_mode = Off;
    mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
    session.auto_start = Off;
    session.use_only_cookies = On;
    session.use_cookies = On;
    session.use_trans_sid = Off;
    session.cookie_httponly = On;
    session.gc_maxlifetime = 12000000;
    allow_url_fopen = on;
```

Can anyone guide me how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, increasing your max_input_vars should work in cases like this. However, whatever server you are using may be using global variables that can override your settings for it and the rest of your values there. I would double-check your server settings first to see if there are global variables overriding any of these settings. If not, then try increasing max_input_vars

Comment: Thanks for your response. I increased the max_input_vars value from .htaccess file and everything works fine.